# spring boot setting up message.properties and errors.properties file in the project structure and reading file to code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot. I want to add external properties files in project structure . Files are errors.properties, messages.propeties and sql.properties file which contains the all sql queries. I get it where to add it i.e \demo\src\main\resources\errors.properties file. Can Anyone of you give me insight how to read from these files to my java code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to leverage what Spring Boot already give you automatically. Anything you put into application.properties (under \demo\src\main\resources) is going to be added to your Environment. I would just take the keys from those three files and create unique entries in application.properites

```
errors.key1=value1
errors.key2=value2

sql.key1=value1
....
```

Then you can use the @ConfigurationProperties annotation to map those configurations to a class that encapsulates each type.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="errors")
public class ErrorSettings {

private String key1;
 .....
//getter and setters
}
```

Now you have a Bean of type ErrorSettings that you can inject into any other Bean you declare and just call the getXXX() method of the configuration you want.

Reference doc:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to ask one more thing if i have to make another file that is errors.properties and sql.properties. Where should i place this file so that it can read . Is it possible or not?